# How can I sort a numpy array to find a minimum coordinate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm relatively new at numpy and I want to sort an array to find a point which has the lowest x **and** y values.

How would I sort the following array in numpy, such that it sorts the first column in ascending order, which are the x coordinate values, and then the second column, which are the y coordinates?

```
[[0.1, 0.2]
[0.5, 0.1]
[0.3, 0.9]
[0.7, 1.0]
[0.1, 0.3]
[0.2, 0.3]]
```

I have seen answers regarding numpy.sort, but I did not understand what the meaning of sorting by an axis was.

Comment: Please include the expected result of your sort, as well as some examples of things you have tried so far.

Comment: What does that even mean? What if one tuple has a smaller x and another has smaller y?

Comment: x_min=min(cords[:,0]);  y_min=min(cords[:,1]) if u only want the minimum coordinate

Comment: @Ranjeet. OP's question seems to assume that those will be the same. What if they aren't?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to sort by the norm of the implied vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `numpy.lexsort`. This performs an indirect lexicographic sort. For some reason it sorts the last row first, so in your case we have to take the transpose and reverse the order of `x` and `y`.

```
>>> A
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.5, 0.1],
       [0.3, 0.9],
       [0.7, 1. ],
       [0.1, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.3]])
>>> A[np.lexsort(A.T[::-1])]
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.1, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.9],
       [0.5, 0.1],
       [0.7, 1. ]])
```

Comment: I was about to post the longer-winded `A[np.lexsort((A[:, 1], A[:, 0]))]` !